# how to declare decimal numbers correctly in COBOL so that they can be used for arithmetic computation?

Tags: cobol

**is there something wrong with the declaration of the decimal numbers.
     I wanted to perform decimal addition and subtraction in COBOL.**

http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cobol_online.php--> i used this website for my code given below

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.  

 PROGRAM-ID. HELLO-WORLD.

 DATA DIVISION.

 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

 01  A   PIC 99V99 VALUE 1011.

 01  B   PIC 99V99 VALUE 2022.

 01  C   PIC 99V99 VALUE 3333.

 PROCEDURE DIVISION.

 ADD A TO B GIVING C.

 DISPLAY C.

 SUBTRACT A FROM B GIVING C ROUNDED.

 DISPLAY C.

 DISPLAY B.

 STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Instead of running things online, why don't you download GNU COBOL from SourceForge and then you'll get to see the error messages telling you your values are too big?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
01  A   PIC 99V99 VALUE 10.11.
```

(You omitted the decimal)

Thereafter, follow the bouncing ball...

Comment: If the result of a calculation has a fractional part >=0.5, the result is increased to the next higher integer. If it's <0.5, to the next lower integer.

Comment: u can post again...i didn't accept your answer as "accepted" in 5min. This time i will. Be quick..

Comment: @ArihanKashyap Not quite there with the ROUNDED. For ADD/SUBTRACT with the same number of decimal places (zero or more) there will be no rounding. If an intermediate result has a digit immediately to the right of the least significant digit in the final result, rounding will take place (if specified) based on that - truncates for 0-4, adds one to least significant digit otherwise (carrying as far up the field as may be necessary). It only rounds/truncates to integer if the final result is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the changes suggested by @Magoo, you will want to include a visible decimal point when you display your result.  Something like this:

```
01 D PIC --9.99.
```

and then in your PROCEDURE DIVISION:

```
MOVE C TO D.
DISPLAY D.
```